# Android how to call Navigation Drawer from fragment

Tags: android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my fragment I have material search bar with navigation button(humbugger).
How can I call Navigation Drawer which is in main activity with that humbugger button in my fragment
Do not get how to handle it inside DictionaryFragment

MainActivity:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            drawer,
            R.string.nav_open_drawer,
            R.string.nav_close_drawer){

    };
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

DictionaryFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) RootView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

...

materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
             //***HOW TO HANDLE IT HERE?***
            //switch (buttonCode) {
              //  case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION:
              //      drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
              //      break;}
        }
    });
       //return RootView;
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/searchBarDividerColor"
tools:context="com.hfad.catchat.DictionaryFragment">

<com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:mt_hint="Search"
    app:mt_navIconEnabled="true"
    app:mt_speechMode="false" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can try where you want to toggle navigation drawer in your fragment, this way you will have to write a method in activity to do whatever you want to do from your fragment, be sure it is a public method:

```
    ((MainActivity)getContext()).toggleDrawer();
```

in your MainActivity:

```
    public void toggleDrawer(){
    //do your stuff
    }
```

Other way is callback aka interface (the preferred one), pass that as a parameter in fragment's constructor and consume that where you want to change drawer's state. Like inside your activity:

```
    Callback callback = new Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(){
      //do your stuff
    }};
    new DictionaryFragment(callback);
```

And inside your fragment you will have to write a constructor to accept that callback and save in a local variable :

```
    public DictionaryFragment() {
    }


    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public DictionaryFragment(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    }
```

And use it like :

```
    callback.onDrawerStateChanged();
```

You can also pass parameters to MainActivity both ways.

Comment: I used first way and its work fine, why is the second way preffered?

Comment: Using callbacks you can avoid dependencies between classes and also reduce chances of activity leaks. Using activity methods also violates fragment's purpose i.e reusability, you will have to keep track about from which activity fragment is opened and use context of that specific activity to perform your action, on the other hand using callbacks you just need to instantiate a callback in activity and pass to fragment, no matter from which activity your fragment is being called, it'll work.